# Issues displaying SVG into HTML Canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

### GOAL

Basically what I am trying to do is:

1. Adding multiple SVG vectors (`head.svg` & `hand.svg`)
2. Storing them into singleton object for
   later use (no need to define SVG later on - it can be used directly from `svg.get('name')`
3. After initial definition & storage is completed - drawing them on Canvas whenever I need to.

*The main idea here is to define them once and draw them multiple times using stored SVG in singleton object.*

### ISSUES

1. In Mozilla Firefox (v61.0.2) it doesn't display anything
2. In Chrome it displays 1st SVG element (`head.svg`), but not the 2nd one (`hand.svg`)

**[ UPDATE ]**

After clearing cache and closing both browsers, when I reopen the project page:

1. Mozilla Firefox shows only 2nd element (`hand.svg`) but not 1st one (`head.svg`)
2. Chrome shows only 1st element (`head.svg`) but no 2nd element (`head.svg`)

### CODE

```js
// Game canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Canvas fullscreen
canvasFullscreen = function() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  // Adapt fullscreen on resize
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    canvasFullscreen();
  };
};
canvasFullscreen();


// SVG draw
var svg = new function() {
  // The list of SVGs
  this.get = {};
  
  // Create Image & add to list
  this.add = function(name, svg) {
    this.get[name] = new Image;
    this.get[name].src = svg;
  };
  
  // Draw SVG in Canvas
  this.draw = function(name, svg, x, y, w, h) {
    // Check if previously defined / added to list
    if (typeof this.get[name] == 'undefined') {
      // If SVG file defined, add it to list
      if (svg !== false) this.add(name, svg);
    }
    // Draw image
    ctx.drawImage(this.get[name], x, y, w, h);
  };
}


// Draw head
svg.draw('head', 'https://richardev.com/public/head.svg', 30, 0, 50, 50);
// Draw hand
svg.draw('left_hand', 'https://richardev.com/public/hand.svg', 0, 12.5, 25, 25);
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: none;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

#canvas {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="window">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

What could be the issue here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do that like that since you need to wait until the image loads which is an asynchronous event.

Comment: But note that drawing an svg with drawImage is slow. You may want to keep them rasterized instead.

Comment: @mpm hmm... I'll try to insert `img.onload = function(){...};`